# Get posts multiple categories

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to get more than one category with wordpress get posts function.

This is what I have:

```
    $posts = get_posts(array(
        'posts_per_page'   => -1,
        'category_name'    => 'featured'
        )
    );
```

And I want to add the category "artworks". I tried like this but it doesn't work, any ideas how to do it?

```
    $posts = get_posts(array(
        'posts_per_page'   => -1,
        'category_name'    => 'featured', 'artworks'
        )
    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the [Wordpress docs](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) it looks like you have to pass category as a number, and I don't see `'category_name'` as an option in the documentation.

It also appears that you can pass only a single category per `get_posts()` call.

So for a single category:

```
$posts = get_posts(array(
        'posts_per_page'   => -1,
        'category'    => '2'
        )
    );
```

Or for multiple

```
$vars = array(
     array(
         'posts_per_page'   => -1,
         'category'    => '2'
     ),
     array(
         'posts_per_page'   => -1,
         'category'    => '3'
     )
);

foreach $vars as $post_array{
    $posts[]  = get_posts($post_array);
}
```

And `print_r($posts);` will have the resulting array.